# Why this script can go directory not exactly same?

Tags: command-line, command, sh

I got a folder directory/A_/abc

the previous programmer was writing a shell script like this

`` location=`directory` ``

`cd $location/A:/abc`

then why i still can go directory/A_/abc ?
I google but still can't find the answer , anyone know?

Comment: Either `directory` is a command that outputs the string `directory`, or you are confusing backquotes (``location=`directory` ``) with single quotes (`location='directory'`).

Comment: I have no idea what the switch from `_` to `:` is supposed mean here.

Comment: i just can't understand my folder structure is directory/A_/abc , but cd $location/A:/abc still working....

Comment: What OS are you using? `bash` may be making a silent substitution of an illegal path character to a standard replacement.